# Angular simple single page app - Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I'm sure this is really simple and I'll get down voted but any help would be greatly apprecicated.

I have a plunker here

https://plnkr.co/edit/5tDXBPt4Ff3mM4ac5hWK?p=preview

I'm setting up a simple single page app.

I'm getting an error in the console.

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

Comment: You should inject ngRounte dependency to module `angular.module('cxoJsApp', ['anRoute']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngRoute` isn't a depedendency, its a angular module(remove `ngRoute` from from your config function). You should be injecting it with inside app module depedency array.

```
angular.module('cxoJsApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Also make sure, when you are using angular API, they both should be of same version, like here you are using `angular-route.js` older version(`1.2.x`). You should use latest version of angular API's. So you should use `1.4.8` version for both `angular.js` & `angular-route.js`

Apart from that you had missed to refer app.js on the page. Also add `missing` controllers in the file

[**Wokring Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DG0W0wuIexQRdcpb75fE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject ngRoute to the module not to the config,

```
  angular.module('cxoJsApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Make sure you have refered the angular-route version goes with the angular,

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Also you have not refered the app.js in your plunker. Here is the working **[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ALTzXldMZfYrbzKcaPUw?p=info)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the module so you can use it.

```
angular.module('cxoJsApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject route provider and add libraries to resolve this issue .